# Understanding base cases for distinct subsequence dynamic programming problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was trying out [distinct subsequence problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/distinct-subsequences):

> Given two strings `s` and `t`, return the number of distinct subsequences of `s` which equals `t`. For example, if `s = "rabbbit"` and `t = "rabbit"`, then the answer is 3 as there are `3` ways you can generate `"rabbit"` from `s`.

I tried following bottom up DP approach:

```
// bottom up - working
def numDistinct(self, s: str, t: str) -> int:
    
    @cache # (i,j): number of distinct subsequences in s[i:] that equal t[j:]
    def aux(i, j):            
        if j == len(t): return 1 
        if i == len(s): return 0 
        
        if s[i] == t[j]:
            return aux(i+1, j+1) + aux(i+1, j)
        else:
            return aux(i+1, j)
        
    return aux(0,0)
```

This gets accepted. I also tried follow top down DP solution:

```
// top down - not working
def numDistinct(self, s: str, t: str) -> int:

    @cache        
    def aux(i, j):
        
        if i == -1: return 0
        if j == -1: return 1
        
        if s[i] == t[j]:
            return aux(i-1,j-1) + aux(i-1, j)
        else:
            return aux(i-1, j)
        
    return aux(len(s)-1, len(t)-1)
```

It fails. For strings `s = rabbbit` and `t = rabbit`, it gives `output = 0`, when the output should be `3` (we can form `bb` in 3 ways from `bbb`).

I dry run top down approach and realized that I need extra check while returning value from first `if`:

[Top down solution dry run image link (not having enough reps to embed image )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIvMR.png)

In above image, each node label is s<sub>i</sub>t<sub>j</sub>. Each edge label is ij.
I realized:

- for leaf `(-1,-1)`, I should return `1` as it represents both `s` and `t` getting exhausted together.
- for leaf `(-1,0)`, I should return `0` as it represents `s` getting exhausted before `t`

So I changed the return value of first `if` a bit:

```
// top down - working
def numDistinct(self, s: str, t: str) -> int:

    @cache        
    def aux(i, j):
        
        if i == -1: return 1 if j == -1 else 0 # if s exhausts before t, return 0, else 1
        if j == -1: return 1
        
        if s[i] == t[j]:
            return aux(i-1,j-1) + aux(i-1, j)
        else:
            return aux(i-1, j)
        
    return aux(len(s)-1, len(t)-1)
```

And this solution gets accepted. Now I was guessing why such check (`1 if j == -1 else 0`) was not necessary in bottom up DP solution. I tried dry for bottom-up approach too:

[Bottom up approach dry run image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM8dN.png)

And looking at leaves of above image, I feel here too I need similar check in first `if`.  But then how bottom up approach is working without similar check in the first `if`'s return value? What I am missing here?

In other words, how bottom up approach is working with `if i==len(s): return 0` and does not need `if i==len(s): return (1 if j==len(s) else 0)`?